Router redirect in react.js and next.js?
I have a two main folders,  main and dashboard. If the user lands on the direct path, the page should load the pages from the main folder.
If the urls starts with dashboard, it should load from the dashboard path.
I have configured the next.config.mjs in following way.
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    const nextConfig = {
        async rewrites() {
            return [
                {
                    source: '/dashboard/:path*',
                    destination: '/dashboard',
                },
                {
                    source: '/:path*',
                    destination: '/main',
                },
            ];
        },
    };

Only the root page redirected to the main page.
If I try to load localhost:3000/faq this did not redirect. Instead, if I load localhost:3000/main/faq it is working as expected. I have to remove the main from the URL.

You can modify your next.config.js and add the rewrites function:
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/dashboard/:path*",
        destination: "/dashboard/:path*",
      },
      {
        source: "/:path*",
        destination: "/main/:path*",
      },
    ];
  },

  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/main/:path*",
        destination: "/:path*",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};

with page structure:
- pages/
    - main/
        - index.js
        - faq.js        
    - dashboard/
        - index.js

So, if I go to /main/faq it will redirect me to /faq.
